# Blazor/Razor CSS isolation and @import-ing fonts

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

What is the correct approach to handling font `@import`s in Blazor/Razor CSS isolation?

I'm converting my Blazor (.NET6 rc2) project to use CSS isolation, however some of the CSS files have `@import` statements that reference font files.

As an example, I have these files;

1. `login.cshtml` - a login page
2. `login.cshtml.css` - its isolated CSS
3. `_LoginLayout.cshtml` - the layout page

In the CSS is the following line;

```
@import url('//rsms.me/inter/inter.css');
```

That imported file only contains `@font-face` declarations, with the font files on that `//rsms.me` server.

However this fails to compile, with;

> Error  RZ5000  @import rules are not supported within scoped CSS files because the loading order would be undefined. @import may only be placed in non-scoped CSS files.

*At this point, I want to make it clear that I'm not that familiar with the behavior of `@font-face` use and how the directive works- but these are the approaches I've tried.*

### Approach 1

First, I tried moving the `inter.css` reference into my layout file, prior to my scoped css-

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@(nameof(MyProject)).styles.css" />
```

This compiles, however my scoped CSS doesn't pick up the fonts. My guess is `@font-face` declarations must be `@import`ed or directly embedded in the CSS file using them.

### Approach 2

Next, I tried merging the entire contents of `inter.css` into my `login.cshtml.css`, and fixing up the urls, eg.;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter var alt';
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-style: italic;
    font-named-instance: 'Italic';
    font-display: swap;
    src: url("//rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-italic.var.woff2?v=3.19") format("woff2");
}
```

The URLs resolve however the fonts still aren't getting applied.

What's the right approach here?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I abandoned the login page that required font imports and built one from scratch.