# @Import rule erroring out while using CSS Isolation

Tags: css, asp.net-core-6.0

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');
```

I am trying to get the to render CSS styles using CSS Isolation in .NET Core 6.0 and I get the error below. Is there a way around this?

> Error RZ5000  @import rules are not supported within scoped CSS files because the loading order would be undefined. @import may only be placed in non-scoped CSS files.

Comment: Try to use double `@@` to escape the `@`.

Comment: Thanks Jason, no joy with that one.

Answer (score 2):

## You cannot use @import in component specific CSS files.

### You can use the @import in the component and use styles locally in that component.

So, for instance, if you had a H3 element that you want to give a google font for, you would add the following to the blazor component. This would have the localised import statement and the CSS that uses it.

You cannot have the Import statement in the component and the CSS in the blazor.css file either. The import statement and the CSS that uses it goes in the component itself.

It looks like the blazor.css files are only meant for native CSS.

```
<style>
  @@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap');
  h3 {
      font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  }
</style>
```

Very important to remember the double `@@` syntax when using import statements so that the compiler does not confuse it for a razor statement.

Comment: Instead of placing the `<style>` elements directly in the Blazor component, I made a component called `GlobalCssVariables` that has the `<style>` elements and import code. Now I just insert that component into other components where I want to use the CSS variables and it works in those components even if they are using Blazor CSS isolation.

Answer (score 0):

When we look at the documentation, we seem to have overlooked the following sentence.

[image]

And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594510/blazor-razor-css-isolation-and-import-ing-fonts) also mentioned this issue and have no answer.
You can check [Razor class library (RCL) support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#razor-class-library-rcl-support), hope it can help you. If not, you'd better find another way to do it. This issue is not worth spending any more time on it.